# Creating a new dataset by filtering original dataset multiple times

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset `data1` like this

```
  X  Z  Y
  1  3  2
  1  5  5
  1  7  1
  1  3  2
  2  2  20 
  2  8  15
  3  9  5
  3  1  2
  3  4  1
```

Y is in reality a column with too many values to manually account for. I want to carry out a computation repeatedly on subsets of the data set based on the value of Y. For Y=2, the subset would be:

```
  X Z Y
  1 3 2
  1 3 2
  3 1 2
```

And for simplicity I will say the computation is to use lm(Z ~ X) on each subset and append the results to a new data set `data2`:

```
  Y  B_0  B_1
  1  __   __
  2  __   __
```

It would be easy if the real dataset was so small and I could just manually select each value of Y, but can I do this in a way that automatically finds the distinct values of Y and creates the subsets (and allows me to call a function like lm and pull out the information I need)?

Comment: Some approaches here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: The current tidyverse recommended of doing this is with `dplyr::nest_by`, if you look at the `?nest_by` help page the examples are pretty much exactly what you want. Or Jon's link provides a more verbose walkthrough.

Comment: @GregorThomas the problem though is that it's not a linear model I want to fit, it's a self defined function. It seems that to retrieve the coefficients is easy because Broom is designed to work with those functions

Comment: I think I see the way to do it in the "Linear Regression and group by in R" question. Thanks